# Custom Fields in Django not displayed in admin panel

Tags: django, sqlite

I am using `UserCreationForm` for registration of the user. Added one address filed as mandatory in the code. however whenever the user is registering on the html page the address input is present.In the admin panel for users the address is not present.

form.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    address=forms.CharField(max_length=250,required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=(
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'address',
        'password1',
        'password2'
        )

    def save(self,commit=True):
        user=super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email=self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    print("inside views")


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return  redirect('./login.html')
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request,'./reg_form.html',args)
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request,'./reg_form.html',args)
```

In the user model all the fields are seen in the admin page,just address is not present. However while registering the user, address input is accepted.

Comment: Is there an "address" field in your User model?

Comment: if you are using the default `User` model from Django , then address field is not there, you may have to create a custom user class or better still, link the user model to another model (with address field)  with a one-to-one mapping

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this code in your models.py this field you input is required, they are added by default.

> ## Email & Password & last_name & first_name are required by default.

```
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['Address', 'SomethingElse']
```

and then in your admin.py

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from .models import User
```

## name of your class and your Object you want to add in admin page.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'admin', 'first_name', 'address')
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'active')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'address')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'staff', 'active')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'address', 'active', 'staff', 'admin')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email')
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)


# Remove Group Model from admin. We're not using it.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

finally, you can check how I add address field into my project
by this link in [Viva-ecommerce-models.py](https://github.com/Mratashnejad/Viva-dealers-thing/blob/master/ecommerce/models.py) and Follow the **Class Address**